# Как вывести ссылки из web-страницы?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите пожалуйста как можно вывести в listBox список ссылок, которые есть на web-странице? Использую элемент webBrowser1. Пробовал так:

```
list.Items.Add(web.Document.Links);
```

Однако, в listBox'e добавлялся только (Collection) и всё, а самих ссылок не было.

Answer (score 1):

Надо перебрать коллекцию Links, например с помощью foreach:

```
foreach (HtmlElement e in web.Document.Links)
{
    list.Items.Add(e.НужноеПолеКласса);
}
```

Или же, использовать привязку данных:

```
list.DataSource = web.Document.Links;
list.DisplayMember = "ПолеКотороеБудетОтображаться";
list.ValueMember = "ЗначениеПрячещеесяЗаОтображающимсяПолем";
```